# How to see the original Debian md5sum of an installed file?

Tags: debian, apt-get, dpkg, md5sum

Here's the situation.  A Debian package has already been installed.  A file from that Debian package appears to have been altered.  However, I am unable to find the original md5sum of the file when the file was installed.

- The original package is no longer available. So I can't unpack the
  package and run md5sum on the file.
- The /var/lib/dpkg/info/.md5sums doesn't exist and "debsums
  -l" lists it as missing.

Is there some other place where this information is kept or is there some other command(s) that I can run to recreate or extract this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that unless the md5sum package is included when the package is originally created, there is no easy way to find the md5sums of the original installation.

Comment: This will not help you with the question at hand, but just to let you know that recent versions of dpkg will generate the md5sums file at unpack time if it's missing in the .deb, w/o needing to have debsums installed. So this should not happen to you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing comes to mind is to try http://snapshot.debian.org/ in order to retrieve the original package. I presume you already checked `/var/cache/apt/archives`...

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I checked the /var/cache/apt directory.  Unfortunately, snapshot.debian.org was bust.